# Let $a_n$ be the sequence given by $a_n$ = 1/$2^n$ if n is even, and 0 if odd. Find the radius of convergence of $\sum_{i=0}^n a_n x^n$

Tags: analysis

> Let $a_n$ be the sequence given by $a_n$ = 1/$2^n$ if n is even, and 0 if odd. Find the radius of convergence of $\sum_{i=0}^n a_n x^n$

I'm not sure how to do this. I'm pretty sure the radius of convergence is 2 but I don't know the method of getting this. Thanks in advance

Comment: How about the [ratio test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test)?

Comment: Makes sence. Should have seen that given it's even and odd. Thanks

Comment: Doesn't matter about the even and odd.  Even for a sequence $b_{n} = 2^{-n}$ for all $n$, the ratio test would apply.

A more universal, "high-power" (but harder to use) weapon is the [Cauchy-Hadamard Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy–Hadamard_theorem).

Answer (score 2):

Well, you have that

$$\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{a_n}=1/2$$

and thus, by the [Cauchy-Hadamard theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Hadamard_theorem), we have that the radius of convergence for the series is given by

$$r=\frac{1}{\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{a_n}}=2$$

---

Note, that the Cauchy-Hadamard  theorem is essentially the root test applied to power series.